# Turning the dataframe upside down and performing groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, time-series

```
x = ts.loc[::-1, "column_1"].eq(0) #First Line of code for reference
x.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")).cumsum().head(35) #Second Line of code for reference
```

`Goal`: I have a timeseries dataframe which  i need to turn it upside down and perform the groupby

`problem`: the `first line of code` above is succesfully turning my dataframe upside down, But in `second line of code` the groupby is automatically turning my dataframe into right order and then performing its functionality.

Can someone tell me how to overcome this(How to apply groupby while my dataframe is stilll reverse?)

```
Sample timeseries dataset:
  Date           

01.01.2000  
02.01.2000  
03.01.2000   
..
..
..
26.01.2000   
27.01.2000  
28.01.2000 
29.01.2000   
30.01.2000   
31.01.2000  
01.02.2000
02.02.2000
```

Comment: Why does the dataframe need to be "upside down" in the first place?

Comment: @MatBailie can you be more specific please !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me working converting `DatetimeIndex` to month `PeriodIndex` with parameter `sort=False`:

```
ts = pd.DataFrame({'public.holiday':[0,1,0,1,1,0]}, 
                  index=pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=6))
print (ts)
            public.holiday
2000-01-01               0
2000-01-02               1
2000-01-03               0
2000-01-04               1
2000-01-05               1
2000-01-06               0

x = ts.loc[::-1, "public.holiday"].eq(0)
out = x.groupby(x.index.to_period('M'), sort=False).cumsum().head(35)
print (out)
2000-01-06    1
2000-01-05    1
2000-01-04    1
2000-01-03    2
2000-01-02    2
2000-01-01    3
Freq: -1D, Name: public.holiday, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Using Internet contractions surely doesn't help when SO is used by people where English is not their first language?

Comment: @jezrael Its not working, after running your code, the groupby is still making the dataframe back to its original form

Comment: @Bella_18 This code doesn't change the dataframe, it createa a new one and prints it to standard io. If you want the new dataframe, assign it to a variable; `x_grouped = x.groupby...`